# GAS: Limitations on Sharing and Permissions for Google Sites and Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't see documentation on setting sites sharing and permissions with advanced options as:

- Anyone with the link (no sign in required)
- Public on the Web

Creating or copying a site defaults the permissions only to the script owner, and would have to manually go to the site itself to set the permissions.

Is this not in the Sites Services yet or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't built-in support for this feature, but you can request it by opening a feature request on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). Alternatively, you can use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp) to call the GData Google Sites API directly, which provides [more granular controls over ACLs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/forum?place=topic%2Fgoogle-sites-api%2FeQb61PDfeEk%2Fdiscussion).